# Flutter request permission

Tags: flutter, permissions, release

I need help.... We have develeoped an App for our NGO. Everything works fine, until we upload to the Google Playstore. The problem is, when you download the app from Playstore, the App dont request permssion, but without permission, we cant use googemaps. When we debug the app from laptop to the smartphone, die permission request comes. What can we do? We have decleart all the permission bei google, all the permission are shown in the release dashboard, but after download the app from playstore, no request of the permission for location.

Answer (score 1):

Use the flutter location package to request the location permission on the start of your app or on the initState of your map widget.

https://pub.dev/packages/location

Answer (score 0):

For request permission prompt follow [this documention](https://pub.dev/packages/location).

The implementation of the package follows the below thread.

https://medium.com/geekculture/get-current-location-flutter-using-location-manager-simplified-bd91249d03b1

Comment: great, thank you very much... I´ll try it by follow you instruction.

Comment: let me know if its helpful